# SwiftUI 3 Scroll vertically in PageTabView

Tags: swiftui

I noticed in SwiftUI 3/iOS 15 the automatic scroll in TabView with PageTabViewStyle() was removed. But If you add a List into the TabView the NavigationBarTitle doesn't change to inline when scrolling.

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabView {
                ForEach(0 ..< 5) { number in
                    List {
                        Text(String(number))
                    }
                    .navigationBarTitle("Scroll")
                }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

[Not scrolling :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wur4U.gif)

Does somebody know how I can have the NavigationBarTitle changing to inline?

Comment: It should not in this case (and never did), List have to be exactly in NavigationView, but in your case NavigationView contains TabView and does not see List.

Comment: I know this. But is there a way to achieve this with TabView?